# How to make a jpg of a BPEL Proces design in SOA suite 12c

Tags: oracle12c, jdeveloper, bpel, soa-suite

I am using: Oracle SOA suite 12c, JDeveloper Studio Edition Version 12.2.1.3.0

How do you turn the BPEL design view Graphic from JDeveloper into a nice JPG you can use for architectural decisions and presentations? I would just make a screenshot, but the BPEL process is quite large and intricate. The screen resolution would have to be enormous for the screenshot to have the required quality.

On a composite level, in the SCA-INF folder, a .jpg file is constantly updated based on changes you make in the composite code/design view. However, for the BPEL process inside the composite, a graphic is not automatically generated in the project file. Is there a way to toggle this functionality? Or do I have to extract the visuals from the graphics.xml in some fashion/other options?

Thank you!

Jesper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the BPEL editor window there is an option to print a JPG on the right side of the set of buttons at the top of the edit window. This will print a JPEG of your BPEL diagram.

Comment: Alright this works. Do you know if there is a way to toggle this functionality automatically? Like is the case for the composite graphic.jpg?